# What is the Japanese reading of this name?

Tags: names, multiple-readings

Given name: 慧敏
Apparently I need 30 characters so here are so more words to meet the count.

Comment: It's an existing word, though not commonly used. You might want to look it up in a Japanese dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering if the name reading was different as so tends to be the case. (I think?)

Comment: Chinese names are normally read by combining the most common *on'yomi* reading of each character. In your case it's the same as how this word is pronounced.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to https://en.pon-navi.net/nazuke/name/%E6%85%A7%E6%95%8F

The name "慧敏" is commonly read as "Keito".

I couldn't find any other non-chinese first name readings.